# Is it possible to save a image in binary in SQL Server to a folder on a remote server?

Tags: sql-server

The following code works when saving the image to a local folder, but fails when I include the Server Ip to save to remote folder

```
DECLARE @ImageData VARBINARY(MAX),
        @UserId NVARCHAR(200),
        @Path NVARCHAR(1024), 
        @Filename NVARCHAR(1024), 
        @ObjectToken INT;

SELECT @Path = 'C:\Images\Profile\Approved';

DECLARE @FullPathToOutputFile NVARCHAR(2048);

SELECT @FullPathToOutputFile = '\\<ServerIP>\'+@Path + '\' + 'abc.jpg';

EXEC sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Stream', @ObjectToken OUTPUT;
EXEC sp_OASetProperty @ObjectToken, 'Type', 1;
EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Open';
EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Write', NULL, @ImageData;
EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'SaveToFile', NULL, @FullPathToOutputFile, 2;
EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Close';
EXEC sp_OADestroy @ObjectToken;
```

Comment: `\\000.00.00.00\folder1\folder1\C:\Images\Profile\Approved\abc.jpg`.. may be it is not a valid path.. print the `@FullPathToOutputFile` before use..

Comment: Write a script/utility on any other language and do whatever you want with files and folders. Stop suffering trying to perform via RDBMS what it's not intended for.

Comment: fails how? What error do you get? Perhaps you don't have permission to write to that file share, but we can only guess without more information.

Comment: I am not getting error. But image is not  getting saved to the folder. But if i remove the Ip from the path, the image gets saved to the local server. Permissions are already enabled to write to remote server. I need these binary to get saved to remote server and not to local machine

Comment: You are not getting any errors because it's up to you to detect and handle any errors while working with sql-dmo. Anyway, I still suggest you to think of some other solution. There are many bad things starting with permissions to `SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER`  it's not supposed to have. It's fine for experiment but not for production.